# Manipulating Two Divs Within a Nav

Tags: html, header, nav, division

I've got a 'Nav Div' with two Divs Inside. Div #1 is a links div, which takes you to other parts of my site, Div #2 is the 'social' div so there are icons for email, linkedin, and github. I've floated Div #2 to the right as I want them in the right side of the nav. Div#2 I want centered in the 'Nav'. My issue is, after floating the social div to the right, when I center the links div, it no longer shows up in the middle, as the social div takes up space to the right. I can't think of a good way to center the links div inside of the nav div, without taking into account the social divs width.

```
 <div id="nav">
    <div id='links'>
      <td><a href="index.html"> Home</a></td>
      <td><a href="#"> Projects</a></td>
      <td><a href='blog-posts/blog.html'>Blog Posts</a></td>
    </div>
    <div id="social">  
      <td class='social'><a href="mailto:tombrightbill@gmail.com"><img id='email' src='images/email.png'/></a></td>
      <td class='social'><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/tom-brightbill/32/559/a98/"><img id='linkedin' src='images/linkedin.png'/></a></td>
      <td class='social'><a href="https://github.com/tombrightbill"><img id='github' src='images/github.png'/></a></td>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#social{
float:right;
display:inline-block;
padding-right:10px;
vertical-align: center;
border-left: 2px solid white;}
#links{
display:inline-block;}
#nav{
background-color:#003300;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
padding-top:15px;
padding-bottom:15px;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
position:relative;}
```

A push in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: As you are floating div#social it should came befor the div#links on your HTML. Also try remove `text-align: center` from #nav and add `margin: 0 auto` to the #links.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I removed `td` elements - for what purpose they were there?

Second, I set `position: absolute` to `#social` and made it sticky to right by adding `right: 0`:

http://jsfiddle.net/4sf8bnmm/

Just make sure to check minimum screen width till `#link` and `#social` overlaps, then set `@meadia` query to rearrange navigation.